# Java String matches error with REGEX

Tags: java, regex, string, selenium-webdriver

I have to split a String if it has this format below

```
String test="City: East Khasi Hills";
```

and some times i may get `String test="City:";`

I want to match the pattern if there is any words after ":",

I am using

```
String city=test.matches(":(.*)")?test.split(":")[1].trim():"";
```

But my regex is returning false. tired of debugging by the way i am using [regex online tool](https://regex101.com/) to test my string.

I am getting a match in the tool. but java is returning me false.

Comment: Don't use Regex101 for Java. It doesn't support the Java flavor of regex. Test with [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) instead.

Comment: Also, how do you split the `String` in the first place, and why?

Comment: i need to get the word after ":", if there is words else empty string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need both matches and `split` both. Just use `split` like this:

```
String[] arr = "City: East Khasi Hills".split("\\s*:\\s*");
String city = arr.length==2 ? arr[1] : "";
//=> "East Khasi Hills"
```

Comment: This answer will still work by giving you text after `:\s*` in `arr[1]`

Comment: For what input it didn't work and what was your expected result?

Comment: if i have string like "city: " , in this case split won't work

Comment: Split will surely work and you will get an empty value in `arr[1]`. Once again **what is your expected result** for this input?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83608/discussion-between-saikiran-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you need to check if your overall pattern matches as expected. So, you can try something like this:

```
String str = "City: East Khasi Hills";
// Test if your pattern matches
if (str.matches("(\\w)+:(\\s(\\w)+)*")) {
    // Split your string
    String[] split = str.split(":");
    // Get the information you need
    System.out.println("Attribute name: "  + split[0]);
    System.out.println("Attribute value: " + split[1].trim());
}
```

Comment: my question is what if doesn't matches the pattern, any way it got resolved thanks for your time @Fernando